# Eagle multiple pads to one pin

Tags: eaglecad

I have a part in Eagle that has two pads for V<sub>DD</sub> (pad 1 and 2) and two pads for V<sub>BAT</sub> (pads 9 and 10). The pads must be tied together on the PCB so I have designated a single pin for each pair of pads.

With the pins set to show both the pad and pin names, I expect to see V<sub>DD</sub> as a pin name and 1*2 for its pad name as well as V<sub>BAT</sub> as a pin name and 9*10 for its pad name. This works fine for V<sub>DD</sub> but not for V<sub>BAT</sub>. For some reason, V<sub>BAT</sub> is showing 9*2 as if it were connected to pad 9 and 2; however, that is not the case.

I am relatively new to Eagle so I'm sure its a simple mistake but I can't seem to figure it out. I have attached screenshot snippets of the relevant information.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't actually an connection problem here, just a misunderstanding of what the names mean.

When multiple pads are connected together, their names are not all shown, but rather are labelled as:

`<First Pin>*<Number of Pins>`

Where the first pin is any of the pins in the group, usually the one with either the lowest number, or first when sorted alphabetically.

The number of pins indicates how many pins in total are connected together.

Essentially you can read it as "Pin x and the group of n pins".

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with this some more, I realized that the *2 portion of the pad name only signifies two connections, it does not seem to correlate to the actual pad name. If one pin is connected to four pads, I observed 1*4 as the pad name although none of the pads had a name of '4'.

It was pure coincidence that the V<sub>DD</sub> pin was connected to pad 1 and 2 therefore implying that the pads it was connected to were pads 1 and 2. Simple beginner mistake, but I will leave this here for anyone else who makes the same error.